# OCL group by element attribute

Tags: acceleo, ocl

In Acceleo I have an OrderedSet of objects, where each object has a string as attribute.

I want to get a container(e.g. OrderedSet) of those strings, where each string is unique.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I got the impression that what you need can be done simply using something like that (assuming your objects set is named `x` and the object's string attribute is named `name`): `x.name->asOrderedSet()`. Am I missing something? (If I'm in the right, I can expand this into an answer, but I would prefer to be sure I understood well the question)

Comment: I currently do so (see my answer below), but according to Ed Willink, this is not the right ways to do it.

Comment: From what I understand, this is right, I think the misunderstood could come from the usage of the word "container" which have a kind of special meaning in the model/EMF world. `x.name->asOrderedSet()` is equivalent to `x->collect(e | e.name)->asOrderedSet()` which is what you want to do. If you want to group the element by a string, you could use `x.sortedBy(name)` that would not remove duplicate, but would group each element regarding their `name` (if this is closer that what you want).

Comment: I used the word "container" as an abstract definition. I was not aware that there is a special meaning. Yes, I use `->collect()` to get the strings and then       `->asOrderedSet()`. This works fine for me but I wanted to make sure that this is a valid operation.

Comment: Totally valid! Don't worry. You can also use the `x.name->asOrderedSet()` notation that makes use of and implicit `collect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I collect all the strings into an collection `->collect(attribute)`. Then I convert to an Ordered Set `->asOrderedSet()`. This will remove all duplicates.

Comment: And it will also remove not-duplicate containers. This seems like a classic case of a presentation of an assumed solution that doesn't work and is hard to fix (you can use Acceleo more reflective library operations). Much better to analyze the actual problem and then come up with a sensible and usually much simpler solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot follow your theoretical explanations completely.

Let's assume I have a template which takes a software library as parameter (lib). lib contains a OrderedSet of functions, where each function has an string attribute "header-path". As I do not want to include the same header multiple times, I want to group "header-path". How would I do so? What to you mean by revisiting OrderedSet construction and which acceleo library operations you have on you mind?

Comment: Likewise, I do not understand your problem. You can happily gather all header path Strings to suppress duplicates. Why do you need to get a container? If you really want the 'container' gather the functions, arbitrarily choose one for each name and use the gathered functions as the containers.

Comment: I don't need a container. I only need the strings. But the concept of not having local variables which can be changed arbitrary is making it very hard to me to come up with a statement which does the trick.

Comment: Sorry. I consider  updating the question to be unethical since it makes all the subsequent thread look stupid. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A String is an (E)DataType rather than an (E)Class instance consequently it has no (e)container. You could do a total model search for all String-typed attributes and check their values - very expensive. Much better to revisit the OrderedSet construction so that the 'container' knowledge is not discarded requiring rediscovery.

Comment: It doesn't matter if its expensive, since there is only a very limited number of objects.

How would I do such a model search?

I already extracted all string in an own collection. Now in "only" need to group them.